# Series with lower limit greater than upper limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

I was under the impression that a summation of the form $\sum_{i=j}^{k}a_i$ where $j>k$ is regarded as an empty sum and so equal to $0$. My TI-89 Titanium calculator seems to disagree. It gives$$\sum_{i=2}^{1}i=0$$as expected, but also gives$$\sum_{i=3}^{1}i=-2$$and$$\sum_{i=4}^{1}i=-5\mbox{.}$$Is this just because the calculator implementation of $\sum$ is not meant to be used with backwards limits, or is there some other rule for backwards limits that doesn't treat them as empty sums?

Comment: According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Formal_definition) your calculator is wrong.

Comment: @Jens That is the definition I am used to also, but is it possible there is some alternative definition to that on wikipedia? Wikipedia even seems to suggest this possibility, since it says "summation may be defined..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the convention of empty sum as well.

I debug a programming problem for a friend years ago and in terms of coding, I am aware of people who do the following:

$$\sum_{i=p}^q a_i = \sum_{i=0}^qa_i - \sum_{i=0}^{p-1}a_i$$

$$\sum_{i=2}^1 i = \sum_{i=0}^{1}i - \sum_{i=0}^{2-1}i=0$$

$$\sum_{i=3}^1 i = \sum_{i=0}^{1}i - \sum_{i=0}^{3-1}i=-2$$

$$\sum_{i=4}^1 i = \sum_{i=0}^{1}i - \sum_{i=0}^{4-1}i=-5$$

That is using this convention, if $p > q$,

$$\sum_{i=p}^q i = \sum_{i=0}^qi - \sum_{i=0}^{p-1}i=-\sum_{i=q+1}^{p-1}i=-\frac{(p-q-1)(p+q)}2$$

They use cumulative sum to compute the summation, and perhaps they did not check if $q \ge p$. I am uncertain if this is an accepted convention or remains a bug though.

Comment: I managed to find a copy of the TI-89 Titanium manual, which essential gives the same formula you gave with just a couple minor differences. If  p-1>q, it converts sigma(expression, i, p, q) into -sigma(expression, i, q+1, p-1), while if p-1=q it defines sigma(expression, i, p, q) to be 0. So I think it was a deliberate design choice rather than a bug, even though the manual doesn't give a reason to define the sum function that way. I think it's probably similar to your reasoning. That is, it allows sums to be separated into two intervals even if the endpoints of the intervals go backwards.